# gawk in windows 7 doen´t handle spaces properly

Tags: windows, format, gawk

Just installed gawk and tried some examples in cmd.exe. A simple command like:

```
gawk {print $1} test.txt
```

leads to syntax error:

> unexpected newline or end of string

pointing at the space after print. Tried braces, quotes ..nothing helps. Only

```
gawk {print$1}
```

without space works. Any idea what to set to avoid wrong interpretation of spaces ?

Comment: It should be `gawk '{print $1}' file`. Note the single quotes around the curly braces.

Comment: But if this at a Windows `cmd` prompt, you'll want `gawk "{print $1}" file` -- I don't think single quotes are that special for windows.

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows command shell you have to double quote "one-liner" scripts, and if they contain quotes, you have to escape those quotes with a backslash:

```
c:\> gawk "BEGIN { print(\"This will work.\") }"
This will work.

c:\>
```

In your case, simply this:

```
c:\> gawk "{print $1}" test.txt
```